# Why does the accuracy drop down and is it posible to store the best accuracy during the learning?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've startet the learning process and observed it a little bit. At epoch 20 the accuracy approached 90% and the loss was about 0.3

Hour later, I foun the machine finished the learning but the accuracy was lost. Why that? Why can't keras stop at best accuracy? 
What does nan as loss mean? Below the output:

```
399/400 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - acc: 0.2168
400/400 [==============================] - 50s 125ms/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.2166 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.2280
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. You loss is `nan` which means that somewhere you have messed up with your loss function and the gradients are too high or your learning rate is too high.

Comment: @Nain if nan appeared instantly after the start of the learning, It would be obvios. But as I describet, the accuracy was going up first epochs, and loss had a reasonable value. I wonder, why doesn't keras stop at the break-even point, when the accuracy begins to sink.

Comment: Why should keras stop? Getting a `nan` after sometime means that your learning rate is high at that point. You can apply `decay_lr` in your optimizer

Comment: It can stop indeed, but should be instructed explicitly for this: keras.callbacks.TerminateOnNaN() . So, if they foresee something for this case, the question can't be that absurd.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. There are callback for this, described here:

https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping

In particular, for NaNs in loss: `keras.callbacks.TerminateOnNaN()`